# Bind and scope in javascript

Tags: javascript, scope, bind

I have to admit that I do not yet fully understand scope and binding in JS. So bear with me.
I'd like to get the result r from the function q1. But I cannot pass it outside the anonymous function in the tx.executeSql call.
The first console.log shows that r contains the desired value. But how to pass it to the calling function?
The framework is mootools.

```
var q1 = function( table, column, where ) {
    sql = "SELECT " + column + " from " + table;
    r = "";
    if (where != undefined)
        sql += " WHERE " + where;
    db.transaction( function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql( sql, [], function( tx, results) { 
            r = results.rows.item(0)[column] ;
            console.log(r + " 1 "); //1
            }, errorHandler );
    }); 
    console.log(r  + " 2 "); //2
    return r;
}

window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    db.transaction( function (tx) { 
        tx.executeSql( 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS nutzer' );
        tx.executeSql( "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS nutzer ( "
            + " id integer not null primary key, "
            + " name text not null default '(unbekannt)', "
            + " jahre integer not null default 0, "
            + " gewicht integer not null default 0)"
        );
        var params = [1,'der Name',10,30];
        tx.executeSql( "INSERT OR IGNORE INTO nutzer (id,name,jahre,gewicht) values (?,?,?,?)", params);
    });
    console.log( q1('nutzer', 'name' ) + " 3 "); //3
})
```

The console output is:

```
2 
3 
der Name 1
```

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You need to use callbacks.

Comment: You can't return it. You have to make the function accept a callback which it will pass the result to.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how async works. Notice the order, `2, 3, 1`

```
var q1 = function( table, column, where, callback ) {
    //                                   ^ callbacks
    sql = "SELECT " + column + " from " + table;
    r = "";
    if (where != undefined)
        sql += " WHERE " + where;
    db.transaction( function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql( sql, [], function( tx, results) { 
            r = results.rows.item(0)[column] ;
            console.log(r + " 2 "); //2
            callback(r);
            // pass r back
            }, errorHandler );
    }); 
    console.log(r  + " 1 "); //1
    return r;
}

q1('nutzer', 'name', function (r) {
    console.log( r + " 3 "); // results!
});
```

Comment: Does that mean I cannot have a synchronous function which reads a value from the database and returns it?